# Comparing columns and printing comments in a new column based on column values

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file with multiple columns. I want to check the following conditions :

file.csv

```
A.B.P;FATH;FNAME;XTRUC;XIZE;XIZE2;ORG;ORG2
AIT;Y9A;RAIT;UNKNOWN;UNKNOWN;80;X;XY
AIT-A;Y9A;RAIT;VIR;67;217;X;X
```

- if $4 contains `UNKNOWN` print in a new `error` column "`XTRUC` is UNKNOWN "

Example :

```
  A.B.P;FATH;FNAME;XTRUC;XIZE;XIZE2;ORG;ORG2;error
  AIT;Y9A;RAIT;UNKNOWN;UNKNOWN;80;X;XY;"XTRUC is UNKNOWN."
```

- if for the same value in $3 we have different values in $4 print in a new column "multiple `XTRUC` value for the same `FNAME`" and if the previous error exist print the new error in a new line in the same cell.

Example :

```
A.B.P;FATH;FNAME;XTRUC;XIZE;XIZE2;ORG;ORG2;error
AIT;Y9A;RAIT;UNKNOWN;UNKNOWN;80;X;XY;"XTRUC is UNKNOWN.
                                     multiple XTRUC value for the same FNAME."
AIT-A;Y9A;RAIT;VIR;67;217;X;X;"multiple XTRUC value for the same FNAME"
```

- if $5 and $6 do not match or one of them or both contain something other tan numbers print the error in a new column "`XIZE` NOK" and/or "XIZE2 NOK" and/or "XIZE and XIZE2 don't match" in a new line if previous errors exist in the same cell.

Example :

```
A.B.P;FATH;FNAME;XTRUC;XIZE;XIZE2;ORG;ORG2;error
AIT;Y9A;RAIT;UNKNOWN;UNKNOWN;80;X;XY;"XTRUC is UNKNOWN.
                                     multiple XTRUC value for the same FNAME.
                                     XIZE NOK."
AIT-A;Y9A;RAIT;VIR;67;217;X;X;"multiple XTRUC value for the same FNAME.
                              XIZE and XIZE2 don't match."
```

- if $7 and $8 do not match print the error in a new column "ORG and ORG2 don't match" in a new line if previous errors exist in the same cell.

Example and expected result:

```
A.B.P;FATH;FNAME;XTRUC;XIZE;XIZE2;ORG;ORG2;error
AIT;Y9A;RAIT;UNKNOWN;UNKNOWN;80;X;X;"XTRUC is UNKNOWN.
                                     multiple XTRUC value for the same FNAME.
                                     XIZE NOK."
AIT-A;Y9A;RAIT;VIR;67;217;X;X Y;"multiple XTRUC value for the same FNAME.
                              XIZE and XIZE2 don't match.
                              ORG and ORG2 don't match."
```

Visual result from CSV file :

[image]

I tried to use multiple awk commands like :

```
awk '{if($5!=$6) print "XIZE and XIZE2 do not match" ; elif($5!='^[0-9]+$' print "`XIZE` NOK" ; elif($6!="^-\?[0-9]+$" print "`XIZE` NOK"}' file.csv
```

It didn't work and with multiple conditions i wonder if there's a simpler way to do it.

Comment: In your code, why are you comparing $5 and $6 to 2 different regexps? Also, why are you testing for a `?` in $6?

Comment: @TenEM: You should look at [Ed Morton's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74662994/26428) answer. It has several improvements over mine. If it works for you then it's better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to add these messages to a new final column.

```
awk -F ';' 'BEGIN {OFS = FS}
{new_field = NF + 1}
$5 != $6 {$new_field = $new_field "XIZE and XIZE2 do not match\n"}
$5 !~ "^[0-9]+$" {$new_field = $new_field "`XIZE` NOK\n"}
$6 !~ "^-\\?[0-9]+$" {$new_field = $new_field "`XIZE` NOK\n"}
{print}' file.csv > new-file.csv
```

This may output more newlines than you want. If that's a problem, it's possible to fix that, perhaps using an array and a for loop or building a string and adding it at print time (see below) instead of simple concatenation.

This script

- sets the field delimiter for input (`-F`) and output (`OFS`) to a semicolon
- calculates the field number of a new error field at the end of the row, it does this for each row, so it may be different if the lengths of rows varies
- for each true field test it concatenates a message to the error field
- regex tests use the negated regex match operator `!~`
- each field in each row is tested (tests are not mutually exclusive (no `else`), if you want them to be mutually exclusive you can change the form of the tests back to using `if` and `else`
- prints the whole row whether an error field was added or not
- redirects the output to a new file

I used the shorter messages from your AWK script rather than the longer ones in your examples. You can easily change them if needed.

Here is an array version that eliminates an excess newline and wraps the new field in quotes:

```
awk -F ';' 'BEGIN {OFS = FS}
NR == 1 {print; next}
{new_field = NF + 1; delete arr; i = 0; d = ""; msg = ""}
$5 != $6 {arr[i++] = "XIZE and XIZE2 do not match"}
$5 !~ "^[0-9]+$" {arr[i++] = "`XIZE` NOK"}
$6 !~ "^-\\?[0-9]+$" {arr[i++] = "`XIZE` NOK"}
{
  if (i > 0) {
    msg = "\"";
    for (idx in arr) {
      msg = d msg arr[idx];
      d = "\n";
    }
    msg = msg "\"";
    $new_field = msg;
  };
 
  print
}' file.csv > new-file.csv
```

Comment: instead of having the new errors in new lines in the same sell it prints them in a new row i droped that behavior and replaced the `\n` with `|` to visually separate errors. in line 5 i put `\\?` instead of `\?`ei was getting an error awk: cmd. line:5: warning: escape sequence `\?' treated as plain `?`` yet it applies the commands on the header too anyway i can skip the header ?

Comment: @TenEM: You could surround the new column with quotes to use newlines inside a cell. To skip the header make the first line of the script: `NR == 1 {next}` or to print it without processing: `NR == 1 {print; next}`

Comment: @TenEM: I added another version.

Comment: @EdMorton: I see that you addressed your concerns to the OP. I just copied them from the question without analyzing them. I probably should have.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be what you want:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" }
NR == 1 { print $0, "error"; next }

{ numErrs = 0 }
($4 == "UNKNOWN")       { errs[++numErrs] = "XTRUC is UNKNOWN" }
($3 != $4)              { errs[++numErrs] = "multiple XTRUC value for the same FNAME" }
($5 != $6) || ($5+0 != $5) || ($6+0 != $6) { errs[++numErrs] = "XIZE and XIZE2 don't match" }
($7 != $8)              { errs[++numErrs] = "ORG and ORG2 don't match" }
{
    printf "%s%s\"", $0, OFS
    for ( errNr=1; errNr<=numErrs; errNr++ ) {
        printf "%s%s", (errNr>1 ? "\n\t\t\t\t" : ""), errs[errNr]
    }
    print "\""
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file.csv
A.B.P;FATH;FNAME;XTRUC;XIZE;XIZE2;ORG;ORG2;error
AIT;Y9A;RAIT;UNKNOWN;UNKNOWN;80;X;XY;"XTRUC is UNKNOWN
                                multiple XTRUC value for the same FNAME
                                XIZE and XIZE2 don't match
                                ORG and ORG2 don't match"
AIT-A;Y9A;RAIT;VIR;67;217;X;X;"multiple XTRUC value for the same FNAME
                                XIZE and XIZE2 don't match"
```

If you don't REALLY want a bunch of white space at the start of the lines in the quoted fields (I only added them to get output that looks ike you say you wanted in your question), then just get rid of `\t\t\t\t` from the printf but leave the `\n`, i.e. `printf "%s%s", (errNr>1 ? "\n" : ""), errs[errNr]`. I'd normally print `ORS` insead of `\n` but you may be doing this to create output for MS-Excel in which case you'd set `ORS="\r\n"` in the `BEGIN` section and leave that `printf` with a `\n` in it for consistency with Excels CSV format.

Comment: I haven't looked at your code very thoroughly, but it seems to add an error column in rows that may not have errors (I'm not referring to the header row). Why do you use pre-increment? I see that you start your `for` loop at 1, but why? What's with all the tabs? They're likely to do something unwanted in the spreadsheet software. Why did you add the numeric tests?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson normally in CSVs every row has the same number of fields so when you add a field to the header it's best to also add that field to every row under it even if that field is empty. I use pre-increment and start the for loop at 1 because in awk every non-user-defined array (as well as strings and fields) starts at 1, not 0, so when creating user-defined arrays it's best to do the same to avoid tripping over the difference. The tabs are to create the output look the OP asked for. The numeric test is because the OP said `if $5 and $6 ... contain something other tan numbers`.

Answer (score -2):

```
printf "AIT;Y9A;RAIT;UNKNOWN;UNKNOWN;80;X;XY" | tr ';' '\n' > stack

[[ $(sed -n '/UNKNOWN/p' stack) ]] && printf "\"XTRUC is UNKNOWN\"" >> stack

tr '\n' ';' < stack > s2
```

You can do the same thing with whatever other tests you like.  Just replace the semi colons with newlines, and then use ed or sed to read the line number corresponding with the line you want.  After that, replace the newlines with semicolons again.